# scale & view at 3d plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, scaling, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

I want to have the graph of this function:

[image]

[Here](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/ctrq9q64) how it looks like from geogebra:

[image]

**I wanted to draw it with `tikz`, so I wrote this code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
        
    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x,\y)=(-\y*\y+2*\y*\x)/2-sin(deg(\y-\x));
            g(\x,\y)=(\x*\x)/2+\y-\x;
        }]
        
        \begin{axis}[
            zmax=7,
            zmin=-7,
            xmax=7,
            xmin=0,
            ymax=7,
            ymin=-7,
            view = {40}{50},
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $t$,
            zlabel = {$z$}
            ]
            
            
            \begin{scope}
                \clip plot[variable=\x,domain=0:7] (\x,\x,{f(\x,\x)})
                -- (0,0,{f(0,0)}) -- (7,7,{f(7,7)}) -- (7,-7,{f(7,-7)}) -- (0,-7,{f(0,-7)});
                \addplot3[
                surf,
                samples=30,
                domain=0:7,
                y domain=-7:7,
                fill opacity=1
                ] {f(x,y)};
            \end{scope}
            
            \begin{scope}
                \clip plot[variable=\x,domain=0:7] (\x,\x,{g(\x,\x)})
                -- (0,0,{g(0,0)}) -- (7,7,{g(7,7)}) -- (0,7,{g(0,7)});
                \addplot3[
                surf,
                samples=30,
                domain=0:7,
                y domain=0:7,
                fill opacity=1
                ] {g(x,y)};
            \end{scope}
            
            \addplot3[ultra thick,
            y domain=0:0,
            black, samples=500,
            domain=0:7
            ]
            ({x},{x},{x*x/2});
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

The problem is that I get something like that:

[image]

which is much mor ugly than geogebra's.

**I believe that the problems are:**

- **The scaling. The unit at z-axis is not the same as the axis in x-axis.**
- **The view point. I don't know how can I see the graph prom the "negative" side, like geogebra's picture.**

What can I do?

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: What is the meaning of `0` in geogebra? (I can not read the syntax). What is the meaning of `sqrt(x)+...` in geogebra? You can not possible find the correct 2D clipping path before your graph is correctly oriented. Try e.g. `view={-50}{30}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The negative angle solved the first problem. PS:`0*sqrt(x)` is to force x>=0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
f(\x,\y)=(-\y*\y+2*\y*\x)/2-sin(deg(\y-\x));
g(\x,\y)=(\x*\x)/2+\y-\x;
}]
\begin{axis}[
view={-60}{20},
xmin=-5, xmax=5.5,
ymin=-3, ymax=6,
zmin=-2, zmax=4,
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$,
axis lines=center,
xtick distance=2, ytick distance=2, ztick distance=2,
restrict z to domain=-8:8,
label style={font=\tiny}, ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
xticklabel style={inner sep=0pt}, yticklabel style={inner sep=0pt},
]


\begin{scope}
\clip plot[variable=\x, domain=0:3.5] (\x,\x,{f(\x,\x)}) -- (5,0,4) -- (5,-3,-8) -- (0,0,-8) -- cycle;
\addplot3[
surf,
shader=faceted interp, colormap/cool, point meta min=-3, point meta max=5,
samples=30,
domain=0:5,
y domain=-3:6,
opacity=0.7,
] {f(x,y)};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip plot[variable=\x, domain=0:3.5] (\x,\x,{g(\x,\x)}) -- (0,6,4) -- (0,6,-2) -- cycle;
\addplot3[
surf,
shader=faceted interp, colormap/hot, point meta min=-3, point meta max=5,
samples=30,
domain=0:5,
y domain=-3:6,
opacity=0.7,
] {g(x,y)};
\end{scope}

\addplot3[
very thick, yellow,
samples=50, smooth,
samples y=1,
domain=0:5,
] ( x , x , {x*x/2} );

\draw (pi,0,0) -- (5.5,0,0);
\draw (0,-3,0) -- (0,0,0);
\draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3D graph with two surfaces]

Comment: Excellent! Works perfect! Thanks a lot!